# How do I download Telegram messages in reverse?

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I am getting all messages of a Telegram channel via GetHistoryRequest. I would like to run a script every day, which gives me the new messages. Is it possible to reverse the order of the messages inside GetHistoryRequest? I have seen an additional property reverse=True, but this gives me an error message. Here is the code (which is available online)

```
history = client(GetHistoryRequest(
            peer=my_channel,
            offset_id=0,
            offset_date=None,
            add_offset=0,
            limit=limit,
            max_id=0,
            min_id=0,
            hash=0
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_history.html)
`GetHistoryRequest` does not have a `reverse` argument. But, the method `client.iter_messages` [does](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages)

Answer (score 0):

This works here  . Downaload 100 message

```
from telethon.tl import functions, types

channel_link = "https://t.me/joinchat/xxxxxx-xxx"
channel_hash = channel_link.strip().split("joinchat/",1)[1]


channel = await client(functions.messages.CheckChatInviteRequest(hash=channel_hash))
    async for message in client.iter_messages(channel.chat, limit = 100,reverse=True):
```